# Determine Fourier coefficients by the values of its L-Series.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, l-functions

suppose I know the values of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^k}$ for all $k=1,2,...$. Is there a way/tool to determine the coefficients $a_n$ from this (which might not be unique)?

I would appreciate any idea or keyword !

Comment: I would try using $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n^k} x^{n} \Rightarrow \frac{f(x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{a_{m}}{m^k} x^{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose
$$ L(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$$
is your Dirichlet series and that it converges in some half-plane. You know $L(k)$ for all positive integers $k$. Then
$$ a(1) = \lim_{k \to \infty} L(k),$$
as all terms but the $1$st go to zero in the limit. This is how to play the game. Now that you know $a(1)$, you consider
$$ a(2) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( L(k) - a(1) \right) 2^k = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( a(1) - a(1) + \frac{a(2)}{2^k} + \sum_{n \geq 3} \frac{a(n)}{n^k} \right) 2^k.$$
You can then compute $a(3)$, and so on, recursively.

So yes, the Fourier coefficients are completely determined by the values of the $L$-series on the positive integers. Further, this shows that they are unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case it is $$  \lim_{k \to \infty} L(k) m^k = 0$$ for all integer $m$. This would end in $a(n)=0$ with your recursion. This means I dont have a solution ?

Comment: No, this means that your $L$-function is identically zero.

Comment: Well I have something like $L(k) = \frac{1}{k!}$, i.e. the L functions shouldnt be zero. But your solutions shows, that there cant be any $a(n)$ satisfying this.